# NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context

Tags: spring, jndi, tomcat7

I am trying to define a JNDI DB connection in a test project with Spring. I've bootstrapped the project with Spring Roo and thus is Mavenized. Here is the Roo script for reference (Roo 1.2.1)

```
project --topLevelPackage org.obliquid.cpool
jpa setup --database MYSQL --provider HIBERNATE --jndiDataSource /jdbc/cpool 
web mvc setup
entity jpa --class org.obliquid.cpool.entity.Person
field string --fieldName name 
web mvc scaffold --class ~.entity.Person 
web mvc all --package ~.web
```

In `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml` I've the following (created by Roo):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
   ...
   <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="/jdbc/cpool" resource-ref="true"/>
   ...
```

I've created `src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/myapp" docBase="cpool" reloadable="true" debug="1">  
    <Resource name = "jdbc/cpool"
        auth = "Container"
        type = "javax.sql.DataSource"
        username = "dbusername"
        password = "dbpassword"
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?DateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        maxActive = "100"
        maxIdle = "4"
        maxWait = "20000"
        removeAbandoned = "true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="600"
        logAbandoned="true"/>   
</Context>
```

However, when I try to run the application in Tomcat 7.0, I get the following error:

> ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context

What should I do to properly define the datasource?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The context.xml file must be in the META-INF directory of the **war** file. It must not be in the classes directory or in a jar file.

Put the META-INF directory with the context.xml in the directory containing the root of the webapp in your source folder tree.

Comment: ah ah! Wrong `META-INF` folder! So I've put `context.xml` in `src/main/webapp/META-INF`, and it gets packaged in the `/META-INF` folder of the war file and everything works, thank you so much!

Comment: @Sikorski: no. context.xml is a Tomcat proprietary file.